# Where can I ask this question about CGI systems used in a certain movie?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I wanted to find out some computer details related to a particular movie, it seems two Stack Exchange are not the correct place, [one was closed as off-topic on Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20082/what-was-the-cgi-of-the-1st-harry-potter-movie-made-on), the [other one on Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/113941/what-were-the-computer-systems-used-for-cgi-in-first-harry-potter-movie-quiddi?noredirect=1#comment196784_113941) is getting downvotes, although a Retrocomputing user suggested Movies & TV as the correct one. So I am confused.

> What was the computer system used to create CGI in the first Harry
> Potter movie, Quidditch scenes in particular? How powerful this
> computer system may have been? I don't suspect Silicon Graphics was
> still the thing? Although I'm purely interested in the computer system
> and its performance/limitations the question was closed on retro
> computing suggesting it may be answered better here.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how things work on Movies.SE so it's unclear to me why your question would be considered trivia. Maybe there's a general rule about not asking what specific equipment gets used? (A search shows that most effects questions ask how something was done but not what specific things were used to do it.) Unfortunately, I don't think there is an SE where this is on topic if it isn't on topic there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't have been redirected to Movie.se by users that have no significant participation on the target site.

In the help centre of Movie.se on [What is on topic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it states

> **Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:**
> ...
>
> - Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title.

Knowing which computer system is used for the CGI effects does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title I would argue.
Your question is likely to be off-topic on Movie.se and downvoted for that reason.

I looked at [Sci-Fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as that was a redirect suggestion on movies.se. I doubt they will be open for your question.  At first I had some hope when I saw:

> - Behind-the-scenes and fandom information

and no glaring exclusion in the *what not to ask* list but going over their awesome meta post [What questions are on-topic, and what questions are off-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350) I concluded that the answer on [Behind-the-Scenes Questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/356/41581) didn't give enough basis that your question would fly there.

I checked for completeness [Video production](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but that is no match either.

Maybe try a sub-reddit, Quora or other fora as I don't expect the specific question you want to ask can fit on any site we currently have.

Answer (score 6):

This is a trivia question, in the vein of niche knowledge that doesn't really serve much of a purpose besides something to ask or something to share at a party or something.

I wouldn't expect this to be on-topic in the network anywhere.

Comment: Wouldn't this be open to interpretation? What is considered trivia, or useless knowledge for one, may be a lifelong hobby or a profession for another...

Comment: The software and (especially) the hardware to render and develop CGI is in a constant state of flux, and has improved and been built on leaps and bounds since a particular work was released.  What would any passer-by do with the knowledge that it was built with X machine or Y software on Z hardware?  Additionally, what actual value does it provide for the network besides someone's curiosity?

Comment: Asking as I want to buy the same machine

Comment: @BartekMalysz Some users tend to downvote questions that aren't really relevant to others, possibly as time grows, since they see such questions as not adding to a database of questions that's meant to be useful for the wider Internet. In fact, we used to have a "too localized" close reason for such questions; it was removed, but some users still don't like such questions and downvote them.